# Java SWT- Synchronizing Table update, Timer task and serial RxTx communication

Tags: java, swt

I am designing a GUI which will interact with a micro-controller via serial port. The GUI will query micro-controller and the data received will be updated in a Table.  The query time is programmable  i.e. the GUI will query according to the time specified from 1 second to 30 seconds.

This is what I have done -

- `Table` for data update
- `Spinner` for query time
- Start and Stop `Button`.

There are two java files GUI.java and serialCommunication.java. A timer with timertask is scheduled to query micro-controller and the data from serial event is updated in a table via a GUI buffer.

Everything is fine but sometimes the table is updated after many values are stored in the buffer.
Kindly help me to synchronize all the data fetch and update. I have used display.asyncExec() for writing to Table.

```
public class practice {

static Table table;
private SerialComm myCommNew = new SerialComm();
private FileOperation myFile = new FileOperation();
private Text txtOutputData;
public int tblIndex=0;
public static String FILTER_PATH = "C:\\";
private static boolean hasDiagnoseData;

Display display = Display.getDefault();
private static int ijk;
private int timerValue;
/**
 * Create contents of the window.
 */
protected void createContents() {
    shell = new Shell();
    shell.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
            System.out.println(shell.getClientArea());
        }
    });
    shell.addShellListener(new ShellAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void shellClosed(ShellEvent evtShellClosed) {
            if (exitApplication()) {
                myCommNew.closePort();
                System.out.println("Port Closed Successfully");
                evtShellClosed.doit = true;
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                evtShellClosed.doit = false;
            }
        }
    });
    shell.setSize(551, 548);
    shell.setText("SWT Application");
    shell.setLayout(null);


    final Label lblMessage = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    lblMessage.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Segoe UI", 12, SWT.BOLD));
    lblMessage.setBounds(292, 64, 155, 33);

    final Combo comboPortsList = new Combo(shell, SWT.READ_ONLY);
    comboPortsList.setToolTipText("Select COM Port");
    comboPortsList.select(0);
    comboPortsList.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            String y = comboPortsList.getText();
            lblMessage.setText(y + " selected");
            try {
                myCommNew.connect(y);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });

    Button btnSearch = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    btnSearch.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            String[] no = myCommNew.getPorts();
            comboPortsList.setItems(no);
            myCommNew.closePort();
            System.out.println("Finished successfully");
        }
    });

    comboPortsList.setBounds(218, 21, 91, 23);
    comboPortsList.setText("Select Port");
    //comboPortsList.setItems(portsNumber);
    btnSearch.setBounds(364, 15, 161, 33);
    btnSearch.setText("Search for Available Ports");
```

//********************************************** TABLE ***********************************************************//

```
    table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table.setBounds(10, 193, 512, 112);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    TableColumn tblclmnSrNo = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnSrNo.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnSrNo.setText("Sr. No.");

    TableColumn tblclmnDate = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnDate.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnDate.setText("Date");

    TableColumn tblclmnValues = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnValues.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnValues.setText("Values");

    //final TableItem newRow = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
```

//********************************************** MENU ***********************************************************//

```
    Menu menu = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);
    shell.setMenuBar(menu);

    MenuItem mntmfile = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.CASCADE);
    mntmfile.setText("&File");

    Menu menu_1 = new Menu(mntmfile);
    mntmfile.setMenu(menu_1);

    MenuItem mntmopen = new MenuItem(menu_1, SWT.PUSH);
    mntmopen.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            FILTER_PATH = "C:\\";
            myFile.readFileCSV(myFile.openFileDlg());
        }
    });
    mntmopen.setText("&Open");

    MenuItem mntmsave = new MenuItem(menu_1, SWT.PUSH);
    mntmsave.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            String fileNameReceived = myFile.saveFileDlg();
            if(fileNameReceived!=null) {
                myFile.writeFileCSV(myFile.saveFileDlg());
            }
        }
    });
    mntmsave.setText("&Save");

    MenuItem mntmExit = new MenuItem(menu_1, SWT.NONE);
    mntmExit.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            shell.close();
        }
    });
    mntmExit.setText("E&xit");

    MenuItem mntmhelp = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.CASCADE);
    mntmhelp.setText("&Help");

    Menu menu_2 = new Menu(mntmhelp);
    mntmhelp.setMenu(menu_2);

    MenuItem mntmAbout = new MenuItem(menu_2, SWT.NONE);
    mntmAbout.setText("About");


    Button btnSend = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    btnSend.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            String newData = txtOutputData.getText();
            myCommNew.sendData(newData+"\n");
            /*TableItem row = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
            row.setText(0, Integer.toString(table.indexOf(row)+1));
            row.setText(1, getCurrentTime());               
            row.setText(2, newData);*/
        }
    });
    btnSend.setBounds(61, 384, 75, 25);
    btnSend.setText("Send");

    final Group grpSelectMode = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
    grpSelectMode.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Segoe UI", 10, SWT.NORMAL));
    grpSelectMode.setText("Select Mode");
    grpSelectMode.setBounds(10, 83, 276, 104);

    final Label lblSampleTime = new Label(grpSelectMode, SWT.NONE);
    lblSampleTime.setBounds(10, 70, 75, 16);
    lblSampleTime.setText("Sample Time");

    final Spinner spinSampleTime = new Spinner(grpSelectMode, SWT.BORDER | SWT.READ_ONLY);
    spinSampleTime.setMaximum(60);
    spinSampleTime.setMinimum(5);
    spinSampleTime.setSelection(10);
    spinSampleTime.setBounds(103, 67, 47, 22);

    Button btnAuto = new Button(grpSelectMode, SWT.RADIO);
    btnAuto.setSelection(true);
    btnAuto.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            grpSelectMode.setBounds(10, 83, 276, 104);
            lblSampleTime.setVisible(true);
            spinSampleTime.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnAuto.setBounds(10, 30, 159, 16);
    btnAuto.setText("Auto");

    Button btnManual = new Button(grpSelectMode, SWT.RADIO);
    btnManual.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            lblSampleTime.setVisible(false);
            spinSampleTime.setVisible(false);
            grpSelectMode.setBounds(10, 83, 276, 70);
        }
    });
    btnManual.setBounds(176, 30, 90, 16);
    btnManual.setText("Manual");



    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    final TimerTask tmrTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCommNew.sendData("Query" + " " + (++ijk) + "\n");
            System.out.println("Timer code Executed" + " " + (ijk));
            System.out.println(getCurrentTime());
            getTableData();
        }
    };

    final Button btnStart = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    final Button btnStop = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);

    btnStart.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            if(myCommNew.isSerialPortOpen()) {
                timerValue = spinSampleTime.getSelection();
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tmrTask, 1000, (timerValue*1000));
                btnStop.setEnabled(true);
                btnStart.setEnabled(false);
            } else
                System.out.println("Serial Port is Not Open, Kindly Check");

        }
    });
    btnStart.setBounds(450, 103, 75, 25);
    btnStart.setText("Start");

    btnStop.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            timer.cancel();
            System.out.println("\nTimer Cancelled");
            btnStart.setEnabled(true);
            btnStop.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    btnStop.setBounds(450, 162, 75, 25);
    btnStop.setText("Stop");
    btnStop.setEnabled(false);

}

private String getCurrentTime() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH.mm.ss");
    Date date1 = new Date();
    String date = dateFormat.format(date1);
    return date;
}

public static boolean recvDiagnoseDataExist() {
    if(hasDiagnoseData)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

private void getTableData() {
    display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(myCommNew.serialDataExist()) {
                try {
                    while(tblIndex<myCommNew.getSerialDataRecvd().size()) {
                        final TableItem newRow = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
                        System.out.println("tblIndex Value:" + tblIndex);
                        System.out.println("Recvd Data Value:" + myCommNew.getSerialDataRecvd());
                        newRow.setText(0, Integer.toString(tblIndex));
                        newRow.setText(1, getCurrentTime());
                        newRow.setText(2,myCommNew.getSerialDataRecvd().get(tblIndex));
                        System.out.println("The Value Recvd is :" + myCommNew.getSerialDataRecvd().get(tblIndex));
                        tblIndex++;
                    }
                } catch (Exception excWhile) {
                    System.out.println("Error in creating row");
                    System.err.println(excWhile.toString());
                    excWhile.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    myCommNew.resetSerialDataExist();
                } catch (Exception exc1) {
                    System.out.println("Error setting flag");
                    exc1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    });

}

private boolean exitApplication() {
    MessageBox msgBox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.ICON_QUESTION
            | SWT.YES | SWT.NO);
        msgBox.setMessage("Do you really want to exit?");
        msgBox.setText("Closing Application");
        //msgBox.
        int response = msgBox.open();
        if (response == SWT.YES) {
            return true;
        } else return false;

}
```

}

Comment: You are going to have to show us some code.

Comment: I have shown you the code, BUT still no replies...............

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like

```
ILock lock....
Job dataFetcher = new Job("fetcher")
{ 
 // override run 
void run(...){

lock.lock();
try{
//get data from micro controller 

}finally{
Lock.unlock();
}
};
UIJob viewerUpdater= new UIJob (display, ""){ 
//override runInUIThread to update your viewer 
};
// add change listener and override the done method
dataFetcher.addJobChangeListener(
new JobChangeListener()
{
void done(){
viewerUpdater.schedule();
}
}
);
```